# dataTable using columnDefs not working if using it to hide specific column and data then passes it's hidden data to database

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables, jquery-datatables-checkboxes

What I did is I have a two checkbox each row. The reason why I have two checkboxes is that the first checkbox is for my status so I used boolean (0,1) second checkbox inside my row is for the ID so that when I update my status it will go to the specific ID's. The problem is this. I don't know much about dataTables and I research and found that I can hide a column using css and configure it inside columnDefs or aocolumnDefs. What I did was I hid the checkbox column for ID so that it won't look messed up. So let us say I have 20 data inside my dataTable, 1st page shows 1-10 of data and then when I updated those 10 items it is okay when pushing it to the server and inserting the data to the database, sadly when I tried to update second page it shows error, the $_POST variable inside my PHP won't read the hidden column and it's checkboxes that was checked. I figured it out that the second page could not read the hidden column. I am really confused on what to do. To elaborate more, I will display images of what my problem is. Thank you in advance for helping!

Reference is >>>> [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372655/jquery-datatables-hide-column-without-removing-it-from-dom)

Here is the first page image where the data's status are successfully updated to my database (this is the first page)

[image]

Here is the second page and it does not update the status of data to the database because it does not fetch the value from the hidden column.

[image]

The error that I received

[image]

Here is without hiding my ID column and it works. The data are updated.

[image]

My whole code

```js
< script >

  //For checkboxes to pass the value to database
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.is_checked_status').on('click', function() {
      var checkAll = this.checked;
      // find the row
      var row = $(this).closest("tr");
      // find the checkboxes in the row
      row.find('input.subCheckbox').each(function() {
        this.checked = checkAll;
      });
    });
  });

// Code for dataTable, solution for the bug during ascending and descending
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dataTables").DataTable({
    aaSorting: [
      [0, 'asc']
    ],
    bPaginate: true,
    bFilter: true,
    bInfo: true,
    bSortable: true,
    bRetrieve: true,
    aoColumnDefs: [{
        "aTargets": [0],
        "bSortable": true
      },
      {
        "aTargets": [1],
        "bSortable": true
      },
      {
        "aTargets": [2],
        "bSortable": true
      }
    ]
  });
  // .column(5).visible(false)

});

// Separated this code due to prohibitions by dataTables.net
$('#dataTables').DataTable({
  aoColumnDefs: [{
    aTargets: [5],
    "sClass": "hide_column"
  }]
}); <
/script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            Emailed Data for approval
          </div>
          <!-- /.panel-heading -->
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">


              <table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th> Control Number </th>
                    <th> Tools Specification </th>
                    <th> Supplier </th>
                    <th>
                      <center> Status </center>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                      <center> Select data to approve </center>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                      <center> ID </center>
                    </th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <?php
                  $con->next_result();
                  $result = mysqli_query($con,"CALL GetAllRequestedTools()"); ?>
                  <tbody>
                    <?php 
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
                    { 
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td><a href='edit_tools_approval.php?ID=".$row['ID']."' 
                    style='color:red;'>" . $row['reg_input'] . "</a></td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['reg_tools_spec'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['reg_supplier'] . "</td>";
                    ?>

                    <td>
                      <center>
                        <label data-id="<?php echo $row['ID'];?>" class="statusButton <?php echo 
                          ($row['req_stats'])? 'label-success': 'label-danger'?>">
                        <?php echo ($row['req_stats'])? 'Approved' : 'Pending'?>
                        </label>
                      </center>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                      <center>
                        <input name="chk_status[]" class="is_checked_status" type="checkbox" value=" 
                      <?php echo $row['req_stats'];?>">
                      </center>
                    </td>

                    <td class="hide_me">
                      <center>
                        <input name="chk_id[]" type="checkbox" class="subCheckbox" value="<?php echo 
                        $row['tools_req_id'];?>">
                      </center>
                    </td>

                    <?php
                     echo "</tr>";
                     }
                    ?>
                  </tbody>
              </table>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>
    <div class="col-lg-15">
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-success pull- 
         right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        <span class="fa fa-check"></span>
        Update
        </button>
    </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-danger pull- 
          right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cancelModal">
         <span class="fa fa-times"></span>
          Cancel 
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS code

```
.hide_column {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured out that it cannot be done during pagination. It is because of the limit of pagination, example is if you have a data 1-10, only the 1-10 data is accepted and 11....n onwards it is disregarded despite of any logic. That is why it is better to think of other logic for the UI