# How to set/get custom data for each row in DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

Is there any way how to add/get some custom hidden data to each row in DataTable ? Every row is clickable and after clicking it should execute function with id as parameter, but this id should not be displayed within my datatable.

So basically, I'm searching something like 'input type=hidden' but for datatable. Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with hidden inputs? Is html5 data-* for your needs?

Comment: I think the problem is not what's in the Datatable but rather what you are displaying on the UI. Is this for a `<GridView>` or what?

Comment: you can hide columns and can access data for any row using the API. Need to be more specific about what you want. Also confirm plugin you are using

Comment: or if by DataTable you mean the datatables plugin for jquery, then look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654633/jquery-datatables-hide-column

Answer (score 0):

You can hide columns by this command:

`fnSetColumnVis( 1, false );`

as mentioned here: [jquery datatables hide column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654633/jquery-datatables-hide-column)