# Datatables: Hide Column based on database value

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, datatables

I'm trying to show/hide column based on database values. I'm using Jquery, PHP and MySQL.

I was using ajax to retrieve the data and hide the column, but it doesn't hide the tbody data, only the header is hidden:

```
$(function () 
  {
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // 2) Send a http request with AJAX http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    $.ajax({                                      
      url: 'account-number.php',                  //the script to call to get data          
      data: '',                        //you can insert url argumnets here to pass to api.php
                                       //for example "id=5&parent=6"
      dataType: 'json',                //data format      
      success: function(data)          //on recieve of reply
      {
        var user = data[1];              //get id
        var table = data[2];            //get table name 
        var show = data[4];          //display or hide
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------
        // 3) Update html content
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------
        //recommend reading up on jquery selectors they are awesome 
        // http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/
        if (show == 0)
        $('#'+ table +'tbody td:nth-child(1), #' + table + 'thead th:nth-child(1)').hide();
        //$('#'+ table +'td:nth-child('+ column +'),th:nth-child('+ column +')').hide();
        if (show == 1)
        $('#'+ table +'tbody td:nth-child(1), #' + table + 'thead th:nth-child(1)').show();
      } 
    });
  });
```

There is no error in console for this. Is there a specific way to hide/show the table data with datatables in Jquery based on database value?

Any help or suggestions, will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't see this post before! [jquery datatables hide column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654633/jquery-datatables-hide-column)

But it helped me alot.

I changed this:

```
 if (show == 0)
            $('#'+ table +'tbody td:nth-child(1), #' + table + 'thead th:nth-child(1)').hide();

 if (show == 1)
            $('#'+ table +'tbody td:nth-child(1), #' + table + 'thead th:nth-child(1)').show();
```

To this:

```
if (show == 0)
        oTable.fnSetColumnVis( 0, false );

if (show == 1)
        oTable.fnSetColumnVis( 0, true );
```