# How to decrease column size of ajaxified jquery datatable?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I Have 3 columns in my dataTable, previously I had 4 and made one of them hidden by using solution [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654633/jquery-datatables-hide-column)

And now my first column is expanded too much (only on firefox), this column contains only checkboxes.

Now I want to decrease the size of my first column by using some function like fnSetColumnVis() ... Please help.

Screenshot : [http://postimg.org/image/9s5wfge3j](http://postimg.org/image/9s5wfge3j/)

Comment: Without code or fiddle I doubt if anyone can help you here.

Answer (score 0):

In your column definitions you can specify column width like this:

```
aoColumns': [
            {
               'mData': 1,
               'sWidth': '20%'
            },
            ...
```

Comment: Can't I do it like this way..

dataTableObject = $('#my-ajaxified-table').dataTable();
   
dataTableObject.fnSetColumnVis( 2, false );