# Datatables use of visible false not working

Tags: datatables

I am using datatables and I try to have my 6th column to be hidden but it is not working. Strangely, it is working for the first and 7th columns.

Here is my code:
HTML
    
                            
                                
                                    ID
                                    Domain
                                    Sub Domain
                                    technology
                                    Certification
                                    Name
                                    Rating
                                    Skill ID
                                    
                                    
                                
                            
                            
                                
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                
                            
                        
Jscript

```
var certificationTable;
certificationTable = $('#certificationTable').DataTable({
                serverSide: true,
                processing: true,
                stateSave: true,
                ajax: {
                        url: "{!! route('listOfUsersSkills',['1']) !!}",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "JSON"
                    },
                columns: [
                    { name: 'skill_user.id', data: 'id', searchable: false , visible: false },
                    { name: 'skills.domain', data: 'domain', searchable: true , visible: true },
                    { name: 'skills.subdomain', data: 'subdomain', searchable: true , visible: true },
                    { name: 'skills.technology', data: 'technology', searchable: true , visible: true },
                    { name: 'skills.skill', data: 'skill', searchable: true , visible: true },
                    { name: 'users.name', data: 'name', searchable: true , visible: true },
                    { name: 'skill_user.rating', data: 'rating', searchable: false , visible: false },
                    { name: 'skills.id', data: 'skill_id', searchable: false , visible: false },
                    {
                        name: 'actions',
                        data: null,
                        sortable: false,
                        searchable: false,
                        render: function (data) {
                            ...
                        },
                        width: '70px'
                    }
                    ],
                order: [[5, 'asc'],[1, 'asc'],[2, 'asc'],[3, 'asc'],[4, 'asc']],
                lengthMenu: [
                    [ 10, 25, 50, -1 ],
                    [ '10 rows', '25 rows', '50 rows', 'Show all' ]
                ],
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [
                    {
                    extend: "colvis",
                    className: "btn-sm",
                    columns: [ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 ]
                    },

                  {
                    extend: "pageLength",
                    className: "btn-sm"
                  },
                  {
                    extend: "csv",
                    className: "btn-sm",
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: ':visible'
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    extend: "excel",
                    className: "btn-sm",
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: ':visible'
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    extend: "print",
                    className: "btn-sm",
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: ':visible'
                    }
                  },
                ],
                initComplete: function () {
                    var columns = this.api().init().columns;
                    this.api().columns().every(function () {
                        var column = this;
                        // this will get us the index of the column
                        index = column[0][0];
                        //console.log(columns[index].searchable);

                        // Now we need to skip the column if it is not searchable and we return true, meaning we go to next iteration
                        if (columns[index].searchable == false) {
                          return true;
                        }
                        else {
                          var input = document.createElement("input");
                          $(input).appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
                          .on('keyup change', function () {
                              column.search($(this).val(), false, false, true).draw();
                          });
                        }
                    });
                    // Restore state
                    var state = certificationTable.state.loaded();
                    if (state) {
                        certificationTable.columns().eq(0).each(function (colIdx) {
                            var colSearch = state.columns[colIdx].search;

                            if (colSearch.search) {
                                $('input', certificationTable.column(colIdx).footer()).val(colSearch.search);
                            }
                        });

                        certificationTable.draw();
                    }
                }
            });
```

So the problem is that, the table is shoing the records fine and everything works except that as you can see, the column 0 and 7 are set to visible false and they are not showing but the column 6 is visible true and it is showing.

I tried also to make sure:

```
alert( 'Column is '+(certificationTable.column( 6 ).visible() === true ? 'visible' : 'not visible'));
```

And for column 0 and 7 it states in the alert not visible but when I do that for column 6, it states visible. It is as if the visible statement on column 6 is not setting it...

Strange thing is that I tried to change column 7 to visible but it didn't show and the alert was showing not visible even if I changed it. It is as if, it is keeping in memory the visible states of the columns set the first time.

Answer (score 48):

I had a very similar problem with setting column visibility. After debugging through the whole init process in datatables, I realized that the last step was to load the saved state of the table. So, I set stateSave to false and voila, it worked!

My issue resulted from the timing of my changes. I had viewed all of the columns in the table before later adding the logic to make certain columns invisible on init. As such, the state of the table, which I believe is set in a browser cookie, had these columns explicitly set to be visible.

There is also a way to override the stateSave functionality through the stateSaveParams callback detailed [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSaveParams).

Not sure if it matters, but I'm using datatables version 1.10.18.

Comment: Good catch.  Forgot stateSave was on.  Thought things were haunted for a bit there.

Comment: This is working! Also, another workaround is to add a column do Datatable, refresh and then remove it, as when the number of columns changes - DT is reloading the state.

Comment: I was having the same issue.  I resolved it just by putting the stateSave: true as the last option. I have .DataTable({pageLength: 25, ajax: <url>, columns: [{...}], stateSave: true})

Comment: Sound like you found a bug to me!

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did and it worked for me ... trick was in columnDefs.

You can also refer to this [url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654633/jquery-datatables-hide-column).. it has live examples

```
$(function () {
$("#demoGrid").DataTable({
    "processing": true, // for show progress bar
    "serverSide": false, // for process server side
    "filter": true, // this is for disable filter (search box)
    "orderMulti": false, // for disable multiple column at once
    "Paging": true,
    "PageLength": 20,
    "iDisplayLength": 20,
    "pagingType": "full_numbers",
    "ajax": {
        "url": "/controller/method",
        "type": "GET",
        "datatype": 'json',
        "data": 'data'
    },
    "autoWidth": false,
    "columnDefs":
           [
               {
                   "targets": [0],
                   "visible": false,
                   "searchable": false,
                   "width": "10px"
               },
               {
                   "targets": [1],
                   "visible": true,
                   "searchable": true,
                   "width": "10px"
               },
               {
                   "targets": [2],
                   "searchable": true,
                   "orderable": true,
                   "width": "40px"
               },
      ... other columns
                  {
                      "targets": [8],
                      "searchable": true,
                      "orderable": true,
                      "width": "40px",
                      "className": 'select-checkbox'
                  }

           ],
    "columns": [
                  { "data": "RowId", "name": "RowId", "autoWidth": true, "Visible": false },
                  { "data": "Domain", "name": "Domain", "autoWidth": true },... rest of code
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why setting visible on the particular columnDefs wasn't working for me was that there was a JavaScript error near it. I was seeing the table but the DataTable setup wasn't running because of the JavaScript error I think. If there is one bug I hate in JavaScript is that it fails silently. It is not always obvious why something isn't working! It really pays to look at the messages thrown in the Google Debugger console! I hope this helps someone besides me.

I am able to set any column visible: false of my choice now!

I really wish there was a JavaScript compiler built in to Visual Studio .Net that would generate an error when you go to run an asp.net web page if there are any JavaScript errors! I realize that it is possible to generate dynamic JavaScript, but I still want some kind of checks for this! I am tired of all of the time wasted when this happens.